# Why did this spam live so long?

Tags: discussion, spam

[This spam question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432363) slipped through the filters on 30 Oct around 10:15 CET.

After 7 minutes it was at -6 votes and 5 views.
Those numbers stayed the same until it eventually disappeared **after more than 35 minutes** (my refresh time was > 1 minute after 30 mins).

The text in [What are the spam and offensive flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work) says:

*3 flags: question is banished from the front page and all question lists except search results.*
*6 flags: post is locked, deleted, and the first revision owner loses 100 reputation.*

So all that time it did not reach 6 flags (or one mod flag, but that's not essential to the question).
Of course, being removed from the front page after 3 slows things down.

Is this more common - are we slow at flagging as spam?
Is this an issue?
Can/should anything be done about it?

Comment: Well its retardedly only in the tag "optimization", its not like it is tagged with something that has large scale exposure. I don't know how other people use the site but I only look at questions belonging to specific tags to keep me from going mental, I had no chance of seeing this. Too bad because it is hugely satisfying to flag flag flag crap.

Comment: It had 5 views at the 30 minute mark. I don't know but nuking a spam question after 5 views is pretty damn good.

Comment: @Magisch Once you open it, it's obvious, yes. I opened the question because I saw it on the front page and the title prompted me to inquire "Is asking 'What X is' on-topic?"

Comment: @JanDoggen my comment was more directed towards the viewcount. The impact of this is very low because only 5 people read it until then. I doubt many people saw it on the frontpage and googled "optimind" because of that. I'd say the spam attempt failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are we so slow at flagging as spam?

Not really.  The only reason it took some time to get rid of this is that it came in at a quiet time.  In the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) (SOCVR) chat room there's a bot called [SmokeDetector](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3735529/smokedetector?tab=recent) that helps identify problematic content. (Other chat rooms may have similar bots, but I only lurk in SOCVR)

It doesn't look like the bot identified the spam this time, for whatever reason.

> Is this an issue?

I don't believe so. In a quiet tag it only took 30 minutes to get rid of the content.

> Can/should anything be done about it?

If the content is around for over an hour, you can always pop over to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), find an active room, and let people know that there's something waiting on a couple more spam flags.

Comment: Yeah, not many people got to see it obviously (low traffic tag, # spam flags approx equal to #views).

Comment: Nice tool that *Smoke detector*. It catches a lot...

Comment: Smokey's a good unicorn.

Answer (score 16):

Let's look at some stats on this. Over the last 24 hours, 31 posts have been destroyed as obvious spam or offensive content. Here are the durations in minutes between posting and destruction for each of these:

```
2
1
3
5
11
6
3
9
120
29
140
1
37
5
4
19
13
7
2
17
7
19
24
66
73
92
1
54
63
60
1
```

This leads to an average lifetime of 29 minutes, but a median of only 11 minutes. A few long outliers skew the average. The 120 minute and 140 minute old spam items survived that long because they were mistakenly flagged as "very low quality" instead of being spam-flagged. A moderator applied a hard spam flag to both to destroy them when they saw them in review.

You'll also note that the time of the day plays a large part in the speed at which these were handled. The ones at the bottom of this list came in during the late night / early morning for U.S. and western European users, when we both see our highest spam volume and when we tend to be light on active moderators and high-rep users who review things like this.

When properly identified, spam tends to be handled quickly (it's at the top of the moderator flag queue, in bright red). It can survive longer when incorrectly flagged or when inattentive reviewers approve it (there were two instances of that in this list, and those reviewers have been dealt with).

The fact that only 31 instances of true spam or trolling were posted in 24 hours to a site of this size and popularity is pretty impressive. Half were destroyed in under 10 minutes, and matters of timing and flag review can account for the rest.