# Do we really want to allow unregistered users to answer questions?

Tags: discussion, registration

I've been contemplating the position of unregistered answerers for a while. Every now and again spam or abuse or nonsense is posted by such users. Just now [an unregistered user posted two abusive answers to the same question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUgkf.png), now posts and user are both gone now.

Events like this make me wonder how beneficial it is to allow unregistered users to answer. The basic motivation behind SO is gamification, and while you can collect reputation and badges without a registration, it's obvious that anyone invested in the community will start by registering their account. This suggests that unregistered users are expected to have a lower inclination towards abiding by the rules.

Most importantly, spammers and "cat walked over my keyboard" posters would have to make the effort of registering an e-mail account in order to be able to disrupt the site (*askers* already have to do this). This is not a huge obstacle, obviously, but it needs at least a few more mouse clicks from bored trolls, which might just be enough.

So the question is, is there any way to estimate the usefulness of unregistered answerers? Are there any statistics, for instance, about average upvotes/accepts of answers by unregistered users? And any statistics about spam/abusive/NAA posts by unregistered users?

For reference: [How do unregistered accounts work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262909/how-do-unregistered-accounts-work)

Comment: Unregistered? I clearly see a username and rep counter in those screenshots...

Comment: @Cerbrus please see my edit with a link. Users can "post as guests", in a cookie-based system.

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware of that feature...

Comment: Would def. be good to have some data here. How many answers were posted by unregistered users in the last month ? How many got an upvote ? How many were deleted ? Then, we could actually determine if unregistered answering is good, instead if just speculating. Shog is the one who would have this kind of data.

Comment: Good for asking about statistics, rather than assuming one way or the other.

Comment: Not sure whether spam or abuse are a real problem. I've never seen any survive longer than 60 seconds.

Comment: *"...it's obvious that anyone invested in the community will start by registering their account. "* Why would anyone *start out* being invested in the community?

Comment: @BilltheLizard good point, that's not the best way of putting it. I meant that someon who actually wants to contribute. It's a bit similar to wikipedia: IP-only editors are always suspicious. There are bunch of drive-by people who want to help, but probably much more vandals.

Comment: It would not make much difference for spam: plenty of it is posted in the form of questions, here and on other sites that require registration to ask (such as [ubuntu.se]). This stuff is not too hard to get rid of. On the other hand, making it easy for users to enter the game by answering is an important feature.

Comment: The theory is that there might be *one* person in this world that knows the answer to a very difficult or obscure question.  And that there should not be any obstacles to let him post that answer, certainly not a login wall.  I suspect everybody knows the detrimental effect, [this web page](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/login-walls/) noodles about it.

Comment: related discussion at MSE: [Can unregistered users be blocked from answering on some sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263867/165773) On one hand, in [Podcast #23](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W25450) Jeff bragged about "low friction nature" of SO. On the other hand, few years later [he admitted (for questions)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107163/165773): "I have decided this policy no longer makes sense"

Comment: On the bright side, a question is automagically protected after I believe 3 spam posts by low rep users.

Comment: The user's original name was **Chimp**, and then he changed it to **Mongol**. :/

Comment: @Pekka웃 [This one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309186/why-did-this-spam-live-so-long) survived 35 minutes ;-) But you're right, they usually are gone quickly enough.

Comment: I think as the same as you, if someone want to contribute in SO, It does not involve much effort to register an account.

Comment: A small stat on this: in the last 24 hours, 24 spam posts have been destroyed. Of those, 12 were questions, which require people to register before asking. Spammers and trolls do frequently register accounts before posting. Services like yopmail, sharklasers, mailinator, etc. make it easy to create throwaway email accounts. Now, the next question is: should SE prevent people from using those disposable email providers to register accounts?

Comment: For normal people, you can take a look at the [SmokeDetector dashboard (metasmoke)](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/users) to see a list of manual confirmed, autodetected spam/rude messages

Comment: It wasn't an answer, but a month or so ago I got a very helpful edit from an unregistered user to an answer I posted on Astronomy.SE.  In this particular case mandatory registration probably wouldn't've been a problem (the edit was from a Physics.SE user who improved my mathjax formatting presumably after seeing it on the hot questions list).  I'm mentioning it as a counter-example because not everything from anons is crap.

Comment: @BradLarson why stop there.  HardOcp.com (a computer hardware/overclocking site) bans all major free email providers (ex gmail) from being used to create accounts on its forums in order to fight spam posting.  /sarcasm

Comment: @Ferrybig, not sure it's a good idea to provide access to that kind of stuff. It isn't really beneficial for anyone to read, and a bit disturbing... Maybe I'm being sensitive, but it might be wise to remove that link... Just my opinion though.

Comment: @isUserAGoat - Their comment does note that the linked comment includes rudeness but I just up voted yours as well so folks can see your warning as well, even with the comments collapsed.

Comment: @isuseragoat I posted it mainly for the purpose of having a list of users who spammed, this can be used to make a list of what users are registered, and who' s not. The amount of spam in there is the spam that comes in stack overflow , and is not mend to offend anyone. Its just for the list of users. Sorry if you feel offended .

Comment: @Ferrybig, not saying I'm offended, we just remove that content from the site for a reason... Also not saying you did anything wrong, just an opinion I wanted to share.

Comment: @DanNeely I was hoping that I made it clear that I don't think all anon contributions are crap:) Anyway, I'm addressing answers in particular. Suggested edits are always peer-reviewed by the community before appearing, asking needs registration, commenting needs rep. The only entrance point is answers for unregistered users.

Comment: [Here's the only good post by an unregistered user I've ever seen... but it's excellent.](https://superuser.com/questions/419070/transatlantic-ping-faster-than-sending-a-pixel-to-the-screen/419167#419167)

Comment: Then there's obvious shill accounts like this one which should also be removed http://stackoverflow.com/users/5938337/minus

Comment: If you can run a query in "data explorer" to find votes on answers by unregistered users over a time span and take an average then perhaps it can be a good measure of usefulness.  I'm not sure if you can tho since i don't use data explorer

Comment: @JamesChoi, Unfortunately, the Data Explorer does not include deleted stuff, so it's not really useful. And I guess quite a few answers posted by unregistered users do get deleted.